# Berthelot’s comparison theorem and functoriality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $A$ be a noetherian $p$-adically complete ring with an ideal $I$ equipped with a PD structure and such that $p$ is nilpotent on $A/I$.

Let $S = \text{Spec}(A)$, $S_0 = \text{Spec}(A/I)$, $Y\to S$ a smooth and proper morphism, $X := Y\times_SS_0$.

Berthelot’s comparison Theorem in crystalline cohomology says that we have:

$$R\Gamma(\text{Cris}(X/S),\mathcal{F}) = R\Gamma(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y}\Omega^*_{Y/S})$$

where $\Omega_{Y/S}^*$ is the usual algebraic de Rham complex of $Y/S$, $\mathcal{F}$ is a finite type crystal in quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X/S}$-modules, $\mathcal{F}_Y$ is given by formal GAGA after restricting $\mathcal{F}$ to $Y\times_S\text{Spec}(A/I^n)$ for every $n\ge 1$ and algebrizing.

In the literature usually one then says “and then one sees that the right side is functorial in $X$”.

This sounds to me like a bit of hand waving. The right side is functorial in $Y$ and who knows if endomorphisms of $X$ over $S_0$ lift to endomorphisms of $Y$ over $S$.

Here is the question:

> Does this sentence actually mean that one can **declare** that the effect of an endomorphism $f : X\to X$ over $S_0$ on the right side **is** by decree the effect on the left side, pre and post-composed with the above canonical comparison map?

For background on this comparison isomorphism see [the Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07MZ) or Berthelot-Ogus.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is even more general than the one you are trying to formulate. That is, for any morphism (not only endomorphisms) $X\to X'$, and any (closed?) immersions $X\to Y$ and $X'\to Y'$ where $Y,Y'$ are smooth, and any lift $X'\to Y'$ of $X\to Y$, the comparison maps are compatible with all these choices.